# GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph]]

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, high-availability, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I have High Availability cluster(Neo4j) in which on master I have gremlin server and on slave there is gremlin console. But when I start gremlin server on master I get following error. I tried the same procedure with different versions of gremlin server and console but I am unable to access graph from gremlin console. When I hit g.V() in console I get error of gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine" in gremlin console.

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-10 apache-tinkerpop-gremlin-server-3.4.2]$ sudo bin/greml                                                                                        in-server.sh ./conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml
[INFO] GremlinServer - 3.4.2
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from ./conf/gremlin-server-neo                                                                                        4j.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report                                                                                         interval=180000ms
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report int                                                                                        erval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= an                                                                                        d agentId=
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval                                                                                        =180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jRepor                                                                                        terMetrics
[WARN] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/neo4j-ha.properti                                                                                        es] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  Grap                                                                                        hFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [                                                                                        class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implem                                                                                        entation [class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFa                                                                                        ctory.java:82)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFa                                                                                        ctory.java:70)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFa                                                                                        ctory.java:104)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$n                                                                                        ew$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.<init>(D                                                                                        efaultGraphManager.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct                                                                                        orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC                                                                                        onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>                                                                                        (ServerGremlinExecutor.java:80)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServe                                                                                        r.java:122)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServe                                                                                        r.java:86)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.                                                                                        java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                                        java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                                        sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFa                                                                                        ctory.java:78)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to j                                                                                        ava.lang.String
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.setConfig(GraphDatabas                                                                                        eBuilder.java:126)
        at org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.impl.Neo4jFactoryImpl.newGraphDatabase(Neo4jF                                                                                        actoryImpl.java:45)
        at org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.Neo4jFactory$Builder.open(Neo4jFactory.java:3                                                                                        2)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jG                                                                                        raph.java:125)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.open(Neo4jGra                                                                                        ph.java:139)
        ... 18 more
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool                                                                                         named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing Gremlin                                                                                        ScriptEngines instances.
[ERROR] DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager - Could not create GremlinScriptEngine                                                                                         for gremlin-groovy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.Scri                                                                                        ptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for c                                                                                        lass: Script1
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager                                                                                        .lambda$createGremlinScriptEngine$16(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:464)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:18                                                                                        4)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:                                                                                        193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.j                                                                                        ava:1382)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.jav                                                                                        a:580)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:                                                                                        270)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.j                                                                                        ava:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.ja                                                                                        va:471)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.j                                                                                        ava:151)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEac                                                                                        hOps.java:174)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418                                                                                        )
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager                                                                                        .createGremlinScriptEngine(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:450)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager                                                                                        .getEngineByName(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:219)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.                                                                                        lambda$getEngineByName$0(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHash                                                                                        Map.java:1660)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.                                                                                        getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eva                                                                                        l$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51                                                                                        1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                        java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                        .java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.la                                                                                        ng.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.                                                                                        eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:378)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager                                                                                        .lambda$createGremlinScriptEngine$16(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:460)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: N                                                                                        o such property: graph for class: Script1
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.                                                                                        eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:697)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.                                                                                        eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:376)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for cla                                                                                        ss: Script1
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptByteco                                                                                        deAdapter.java:65)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(                                                                                        PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjec                                                                                        tGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:45)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.                                                                                        eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:674)
        ... 27 more
[WARN] ServerGremlinExecutor - Could not initialize gremlin-groovy GremlinScript                                                                                        Engine as init script could not be evaluated
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gr                                                                                        emlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.j                                                                                        ava:375)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:19                                                                                        34)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.lambda                                                                                        $new$4(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:141)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:559)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>                                                                                        (ServerGremlinExecutor.java:136)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServe                                                                                        r.java:122)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServe                                                                                        r.java:86)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.                                                                                        java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gremlin-groovy is not an availabl                                                                                        e GremlinScriptEngine
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.                                                                                        registerLookUpInfo(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:95)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.                                                                                        getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:58)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eva                                                                                        l$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:51                                                                                        1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.                                                                                        java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor                                                                                        .java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the session OpProcessor.
[INFO] OpLoader - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
[INFO] TraversalOpProcessor - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with si                                                                                        ze 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
[INFO] GremlinServer - idleConnectionTimeout was set to 0 which resolves to 0 se                                                                                        conds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
[INFO] GremlinServer - keepAliveInterval was set to 0 which resolves to 0 second                                                                                        s when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo with o                                                                                        rg.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-string                                                                                        d with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with o                                                                                        rg.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerp                                                                                        op.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
[INFO] AbstractChannelizer - Configured application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0 with or                                                                                        g.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1,                                                                                         gremlin pool of 1 and boss thread pool of 1.
[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your issue or not, but you need to install the Gremlin Server Neo4j plugin so that the appropriate classes are present with this command:

```
bin/gremlin-server.sh install org.apache.tinkerpop neo4j-gremlin 3.4.3
```

before starting the server. If that is not your issue, then you may need to update your question with more details, specifically, (1) a cleaned up posting of your server output as there is some spacing in your current output that makes it hard to read and (2) your Gremlin Server initialization script as well as your "neo4j-ha.properties" file.

Comment: I already used bin/gremlin-server.sh install org.apache.tinkerpop neo4j-gremlin 3.4.3 this command before server startup. This is how I start gremlin server : sudo bin/gremlin-server.sh ./conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml and for Gremlin Console : sudo ./bin/gremlin.sh.  Please find server logs and neo4j-ha.properties here : <https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uePk2yor4Ksa_qBmMTcSDs-YOavCbTBL>

Comment: please edit your question and paste the text of those files there so that other people reading this can quickly see if their problem matches yours.